# How to better couple my classes and deal with dynamic property history

Tags: python

I am trying to build a program to keep track of all the food items consumed in my house.  I also want to have a rough estimate of how those are segregated between all members of my house. For that I have a `class House` that have attributes representing all the members of the house and all the shopping receipts:

```
class House:

    def __init__(self, address: 'Address' = None, members: typing.Set['Members'] = None, receipts: typing.Set['Receipt'] = None) -> None:
        self.address = address
        if members is None:
            self.members = set()
        else:
            self.members = set(members)
        if receipts is None:
            self.receipts = set()
        else:
            self.receipts = set(receipts)
```

The `class Receipt` is an abstraction for the shopping receipt and it has an attribute called `receipt_lines` which is a list of objects called `ReceiptLine`. Each instance of `ReceiptLine` is a dataclass with the following attributes:

```
@attr.s
class ReceiptLine:

    description: str = attr.ib()
    qty: str = attr.ib(converter=float)
    unit: str = attr.ib()
    price: float = attr.ib(converter=float)
    local_gtin: str = attr.ib()
    product = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(Product))
```

The `product` attribute is as follow:

```
@attr.s(frozen=True)
class Product:

    name: str = attr.ib()
    brand: str = attr.ib()
    category: str = attr.ib()
    gtin: str = attr.ib()
    nutri_facts = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(NutriFacts))
    ingredients = attr.ib(
        type=typing.Set[Ingredient], default=attr.Factory(set))
```

For the `class Member` I have:

```
class Patient:

    def __init__(self, first_name: str, email: str, phone: str, age: int, gender: str, last_name=None, weekly_meals: WeeklyMeals = None) -> None:
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.weekly_meals = weekly_meals
        self.products = list()
        self.meals = list()
        self.nutrition_plan = list()
```

My idea is to have `weekly_meals` holding information about which meals of the week that specific member eats at home, `products` would be a list of products that only this specific member consumes and `nutrition_plan` would hold information about the amount of food this specific member consumes.

With that (`weekly_meals`, `products` and `nutrition_plan`), every time a new `Receipt` is added to a `House`, I would like to partition every `ReceiptLines` between each `Member`.

Now, after the partition, I am note sure if I should place this information on `House`, `Member` or even a third class. Today a `Member` does not know anything about `House`, `Receipt` or `ReceiptLine`, but I am thinking I should have an new attribute on `Member` to hold its participation on a `ReceiptLine` and let `House` do the segregation and also set the value for this new attribute. Is it OK to that way?

Also, I think that some things could change in the future. For example, a `Member` `weekly_meals` could change, but that should affect only the partition of the new `Receipts`. How should I approach this problem?

tks

Comment: btw `self.members = set(members) if members else set()` is clearer IMHO.

Comment: What do you plan on *doing* with this data?  and what do you mean by 'partition'?  Is there any reason that e.g. one should be able to get from a 'house' to the meals that member eats that week?

Comment: Tks @2e0byo. Ideally I would like to distribute every item from a receipt between all the members of a house. Even parts of a item (that is what I mean by partition). For example, if there is 1kg of potatoes on a receipt, I would "send" 250g for on member, 200g for another, 300g for another, and so one. That division would based on the members attributes (weekly_meal, nutrition_plan, product). The House is justo to hold and centralize all the members and receipts and then try to estimate each member food intake without the need of much recurrent input from the members.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing I would do with a method on the container class, treating the other classes as pure data storage.  State changes in between method calls will only be reflected in new calls, as requested.

Comment: Could u detailed it a little farther, pls? Sorry, I don't have much experience coding. Could my house class be the container? And I would have some 'allocate' method on it that would be called to change the data stored on the other data storage classes? I would have another attribute on the 'member' class to store that members part of an item on a Receipt as returned by the 'allocate' method? Is something like that you mean? I am starting to study design patterns, but I still have a lot to go. Tks again

Comment: Exactly.  The best thing now though is to try writing it: when you have a working example you might like to post it to codereview.SE for feedback.  The best way to learn coding is to do it! :)

Comment: Great. Tks @2e0byo